# Expected number of trials until consecutive fail and two successes (FSS) for Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider a Bernoulli trial with the probability of success $p$. The probability of failure is $q=1-p$.

To find the expected number of trials to get consecutive fail and two successes (F-S-S).

In the book "A first course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross, the following formula to calculate the probability of a run of $m$ failures before a run of $n$ successes has been stated

$$P(\text{run of m failures before a run of n succeses})= \frac{q^{m-1}(1-p^n)}{q^{m-1}+p^{n-1}-q^{m-1}p^{n-1}}$$

For example, consider $m = 1$, $n = 2$, and $p=0.5$. Then number of trials required are calculated by $1/P$. I get $1.33$. I understand that this answer is logically wrong (we need at least 3 trials to get F-S-S) but I am struggling to understand why.

Comment: Your image is not visible, consider adding it as part of the post itself.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to add images, so I added formula in math block. Thanks for editing @ananta

Comment: I am not sure of the explanation, so you should take the following **guess-work** with a **large grain of salt**.  It seems that the quoted probability $~P,~$ applied to this problem represents the probability of having at least one failure, **anytime** before having at least two consecutive successes.  Alternatively, let $~Q~$ denote the probability of having $~n~$ successes **immediately** following the $~m~$ failures.  Then, it would seem to me that the expected number of trials before getting $~m~$ failures, immediately followed by $~n~$ successes would be $~(1/Q),~$ rather than $~(1/P).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can model this as an absorbing Markov chain with transition matrix

$$
P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 p & 1-p & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1-p & p & 0 \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Write $$
P = \begin{pmatrix}Q&R\\\mathbf 0&I\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $Q$ is the submatrix of $P$ corresponding to transitions between transient states and $R$ the submatrix of $P$ corresponding to transitions from transient states to the absorbing tahte. Then the expected number of steps before being absorbed when starting in transient state $i$ is given by the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry of $N\mathbf 1$, where
$$
N := \sum_{k=0}^\infty Q^k = (I-Q)^{-1}.
$$
A straightforward computation yields the result,
$$
\frac1{p^2(1-p)}.
$$

Comment: For example, I want to calculate expected number of trials until S-S-S-S-F. $p = 0.4$, $q = 1 - 0.4 = 0.6$
I will need to do following. 
$$ \frac{1}{0.4^4 * 0.6} $$
Do I understand correctly?

Comment: That happens to be the correct result, for that particular pattern, but more complex patterns will not have such simple closed forms.